# Trying to understand Functional Programming sample

Tags: functional-programming

I was given some sample questions in functional programming (Something I have rarely been exposed to). 
My first thought was to throw this in an F# project in Visual Studio, but it wont run. Can someone tell me what language this actually is, or if it is f# what is wrong with it? Looking at it, the output should be `monday friday`, right?

```
* (defun both-ends-with-special ()(setf whole-list (cons (first whole-list) (last whole-list))))
* (setf whole-list ‘(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday))
* (both-ends-with-special)
```

I'm thinking the first line declares a function that concats the first and last elements in the variable declared on the second line, then the third line calls it?

Comment: It looks like common lisp.

Comment: Was I correct in assuming what it does?

Comment: Yes, it looks like `both-ends-with-special` sets the `whole-list` variable to be `'(monday friday)`. You might find [practical common lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) helpful.

Comment: It is either Common Lisp or Emacs Lisp. And used in a pretty non-functional style, since it does a bunch of mutation.

Comment: Since this is definitely not F#, I removed the tag